# how to store a value of a list and use it in another method

Tags: c#

I have a list that i need to use the result of in another method.

```
 public void GetTextSize()
        {
            List<int>TextSize = new List<int>();
            if (SmallCustomTextSize)TextSize.Add(12);
            if (MediumCustomTextSize) TextSize.Add(14);
            if (LargeCustomTextSize) TextSize.Add(16);
            if (VeryLargeCustomTextSize) TextSize.Add(17);
            var result = TextSize;
        }
```

I have tried to intialize the list on the top of the page but then the list is null if i wanna use it, 
how can i keep the result of this and use it elsewhere?

Comment: Err, can't you just [return the list from the method?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#return-values)

Comment: @cbr thanks, i believe that no question is a stupid question if person is starting to learn something so complex such as programming. If you think there is, then dont display post from new contributors

Comment: Oh, I did not intend to be mean. I apologise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting null to the initialized list, because you are not assigning `TextSize` correctly.

```
...
public List<int> TextSizeResult { get; set; }  //Top initialized 
...
public void GetTextSize()
{
     List<int>TextSize = new List<int>();
     if (SmallCustomTextSize)TextSize.Add(12);
     if (MediumCustomTextSize) TextSize.Add(14);
     if (LargeCustomTextSize) TextSize.Add(16);
     if (VeryLargeCustomTextSize) TextSize.Add(17);
     // var result = TextSize; <--- This line creating local variable called result.
     //Instead of assigning `TextSize` to local variable, assign it to class level property
     TextSizeResult = TextSize; //This was missing
}
```

---

**Another approach:**

You can return same list from this function and use it in another function

```
public List<int> GetTextSize()
{     //^^^^^^^^^ Change void to List<int> i.e type of list
       List<int>TextSize = new List<int>();
       if (SmallCustomTextSize)TextSize.Add(12);
       if (MediumCustomTextSize) TextSize.Add(14);
       if (LargeCustomTextSize) TextSize.Add(16);
       if (VeryLargeCustomTextSize) TextSize.Add(17);
       return TextSize;  //Instead of assigning it to result return it.
}
```

Now this will give you flexibility of passing `TextSize` list in another function.

Like,

```
...
var textSize = GetTextSize();
var result = AnotherFunction(textSize);
...
```

Comment: ok, thank you and i already have one parameter in the method where i need to use the result or textSize?

Comment: No need to use any parameter, you need to return a list

Comment: private static List<Article> FindAllArticlesForPurchase(List<Article> allArticles){} that is the another method where i need the value

Comment: thank you for the edit i would give you votes up but i dont have enough points as i am new contributor